# Wordpress Export results in This site can not be reached

Tags: wordpress

visiting wp-admin/export.php works just fine but when I click Export All I receive the error.  If I select only one of the many selections it makes it to display the download then the file fails with Failed-Network Error.

I have removed all plugins and set the theme to Twenty Nineteen and receive the same results.

I went through permissions to ensure that all folders are set to 755 and files to 644.

What could I be missing?

Comment: Have you enabled debug via `WP_DEBUG`, `WP_DEBUG_LOG` and `WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY` to see if there are any errors?

Comment: Sounds like there's a problem with your installation, you could try [this plugin](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/health-check/) to find any issues. Helped me a lot with these type of problems!

Comment: I tried your plugin and it came up with nothing wrong other than telling me to delete unused plugins.  Also I have all three functions set to true and nothing shows up and it does not create a log file.